# How to raise an event when a short cut key was used

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, user-controls

I have a UserControl in VB.Net named vpsGridView, it has a MenuStrip name Toolbar and a Datagridview named dtgvpsGV. My MenuStrip have two ToolStripMenu, tsAddRow with (Ctrl + Ins) shortcut key and tsDeleteRow with (Ctrl + Del) shortcut key.

Here is my code:

```
Public Event vps_ItemClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Private Sub Toolbar_ItemClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent vps_ItemClick(sender, e)
End Sub

Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim btn As ToolStripMenuItem = Nothing
    Dim txt As ToolStripTextBox = Nothing

    'Loop through MenuStrip items for Custom Handler
    For x As Integer = 0 To Toolbar.Items.Count - 1
        If Toolbar.Items(x).GetType.ToString = "System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem" Then
            btn = DirectCast(Toolbar.Items(x), ToolStripMenuItem)

            RemoveHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Toolbar_ItemClick
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf Toolbar_ItemClick
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

My problem is when I use the shortcut keys, vps_ItemClick was not firing, but if I use click it works fine. Can you help me identify what's wrong or suggest a better way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that a `ToolStripMenuItem` doesn't raise a `Click` event when its shortcut keys are pressed and that is simply not the case unless something is actually broken. The first thing I'd suggest doing is creating handlers for each menu item the usual way, i.e. by double-clicking them in the designer, and then setting a breakpoint on each one and test whether it gets hit when you press the shortcut keys.

Comment: Thank you Sir for you response.On my code above, when I press the shortcut key, the code triggers / execute the Toolbar_ItemClick Sub, but the RaiseEvent vps_ItemClick(sender, e) inside was not firing. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: If your `Toolbar_ItemClick` method is being called then that `RaiseEvent` will be executed.  Either it will raise the event or an exception will be thrown somewhere.  If there's no exception then it's working and you're just doing something else wrong somewhere.  You need to debug your code properly, i.e. with breakpoints and stepping through the code.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, here a further description of my problem. Again, i created a UserControl name vpsGridView, I used it on another form twice (it was for the child table) Ex. DGrid_1 and DGrid_2. Yes the event was executed without problem. But I cannot determine the which one fired the event, because they have the same ShortCut Key. How can I determine which one fired.

Comment: You're now describing something unrelated to the topic of this question.  If you now have a different question then mark this one as answered and post a new question on the new topic.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need to be writing most of that code.  There's no need to use `AddHandler` here.  Just let the IDE generate the event handler for you as usual.  To create a single method to handle an event of multiple components:

1. Select the multiple components in the designer.
2. Open the Properties window.
3. Click the Events button.
4. Double-click the event of interest.

The IDE will then generate a single method with multiple events in the `Handles` clause.  You can change the name of the method to be more generic if you like.  In that case, you might end up with something like this:

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItems_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SecondToolStripMenuItem.Click,
                                                                               FirstToolStripMenuItem.Click

End Sub
```

I would then recommend that you stick to the .NET convention for naming and raising events, i.e.

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItems_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SecondToolStripMenuItem.Click,
                                                                               FirstToolStripMenuItem.Click
    OnItemClick(EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Public Event ItemClick As EventHandler

Protected Overridable Sub OnItemClick(e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ItemClick(Me, e)
End Sub
```

Note that the object that raised the event should ALWAYS be the `sender`.  You should NEVER pass on the `sender` from an event handler to another event.  If you want your `ItemClick` event to specify which item was clicked then you would do that through the `e` parameter, e.g.

```
Public Class ItemClickEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public ReadOnly Property Item As ToolStripMenuItem

    Public Sub New(item As ToolStripMenuItem)
        Me.Item = item
    End Sub

End Class
```

and then:

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItems_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SecondToolStripMenuItem.Click,
                                                                               FirstToolStripMenuItem.Click
    OnItemClick(New ItemClickEventArgs(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)))
End Sub

Public Event ItemClick As EventHandler(Of ItemClickEventArgs)

Protected Overridable Sub OnItemClick(e As ItemClickEventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ItemClick(Me, e)
End Sub
```